# Predicting a final exam score from arbitrary set of practice exams

Tags: machine-learning, regression, naive-bayes-classifier

I posed this question [to math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535788/regression-or-na%c3%afve-bayes-for-irregular-matrix) without response, and feel it is better suited here. I am writing an application to predict a final exam score given at least one tuple, where the tuple represents the results of a practice exam:

```
(score, exam_name, date_taken[optional])
```

Users input practice exam scores and, later, their official exam score (date required); not all users take all available practice exams. The dataset can be represented like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c & d & e & f\\
g\\
h & i & & j\\
k & l & m &&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
(actual,date)\\
(actual,date)\\ 
(actual,date)\\
(null,date)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Each row is a `user`. Each column in the first matrix is a particular practice exam; the second matrix is the score of the final exam (`actual`) and date taken. Each element in the first matrix is a tuple of the form described above.

Users complete an arbitrary combination of practice exams. The `user` represented by the 4th row has inputted four events (four practice exams), the date he plans to take the official exam, but not his actual score; as such, we want to provide him with a prediction.

**What model(s) might be suited for this problem?**

I have a hunch that naïve Bayes might be best because of the "incompleteness" of the matrix, and because I want to provide a prediction to the user after *any* input of data (i.e., user inputting a single tuple with no date, `(512, mcat_24)`, should still receive a prediction). The feature of the problem most difficult to me is the fact that not all users take all practice exams; I'm not sure how to formalize that mathematically. I am working my way through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03865.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, which may help.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03865.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most natural way to design this problem is indeed with missing values, and of course that means using a learning algorithm which can deal with these. Additionally to NB I think decision trees (at least some implementations) can handle missing value as well.